# CORS error when trying to fetch an API with API key

Tags: javascript, next.js, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch an API with an API Key in my nextJS project but It does not read my Key I believe and it also shows me this CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://fleetapi-pt.cartrack.com/rest/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I don't know how to solve it I do not have access to the server where the API is. My fetch is something like this (I took the `apikey` off cuz I dont want to expose it on the internet):

```
const apiUrl = 'https://fleetapi-pt.cartrack.com/rest/vehicles';

// API key for authentication
const apiKey = 'my_api_key';

let result;

// Make a GET request with authentication using the Fetch API
fetch(apiUrl, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    },
})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(protectedData => {
    result = protectedData;
    console.log('Protected Data:', protectedData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Hey, I'm currently building [blockedbycors.dev](https://blockedbycors.dev/) which aims to provide support for exactly these types of issues. You may want to try whether the CORS debugger can help you.
Two hints from my side:
- the server has to accept sending additional header, like the Authorization header
- if you don't have access to the server configuration you are out of luck with solving any CORS issues